# Splash Screen Issue in Android Studio: Error "Unfortunately MyApplication has stopped", java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am running a splash screen for 5 seconds. Once that time is over, instead of going to the MainActivity.java, my app terminates and gives me an error saying "Unfortunately My Application has stopped".

Please check out the LogCat below.

I am also thinking I might have written action android:name and category android:name incorrectly in AndroidManifest.xml.

I am very new at programming and am learning Android Studio off of an Eclipse tutorial. I would really appreciate detailed guidance.

Below is my code.

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int counter = 0;
    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });





        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter = counter - 1;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Splash.xml**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by Psp on 2016-02-02.
 */
public class Splash extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle PLovesMishti) {
        super.onCreate(PLovesMishti);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264): ***FATAL EXCEPTION: main***

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264): Process: com.example.android.myapplication, PID: 4264

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264): ***java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.myapplication/com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference***

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2071)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)

02-03 23:53:45.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
```

Comment: Problem is in `MainActivity ` instead of  `Splash `

Comment: Post your `MainActivity.java` code

Comment: also provide `activity_main.xml` code...

Comment: **Strongly** consider using a [branded launch screen](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd) rather than a splash screen activity.

Comment: Try with Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);  Where is your mainactivity code? instead of main activity you have posted xml code!!1

Comment: Check line 18 in your MianActivity.java, you call some widget withour initializing.

Comment: Fixed. Changed the intent code lines by @ELITE and it worked. You guys are awesome! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change lines

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity");
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

to

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

You are getting views before activity instantiation

```
Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
```

remove these line from global declaration and add it to `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

```
public void onCreate() {
    ....
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ....
    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Problem is your  AndroidMenifest.xml  code remove some code only.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Change below in MainActivity.java file -

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity");
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

To the code given below -

```
Intent openStartingPoints = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line :

```
 Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity");
    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

to

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

It might helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line and paste your main activityfor null pointer exceptoion because it seems some thing you are going to wrong with initialize your main activity views .

Intent i= new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

The log cat is saying that you are pointing to a null object basically means the computer see the object but it has a value of 0 witchs means ethier its not there or it doesnt have data might wanna check the location where your trying to pull the spash.xml your problem is in the main activity and also on splash.xml you have time.start(); with no stoping point witch could make it to crash because your in a never ending loop

Answer (score 0):

Replace line from finally block

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity");
    startActivity(openStartingPoint);

to 


 Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.java);
    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

Main Activity should be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        int counter = 0;
        Button add; // Declare here 
        Button sub ;
        TextView display;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize here after setContentView

         add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
         sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
         display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });





            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v){

                    counter++;
                    display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

                }
            });

            sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    counter = counter - 1;
                    display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

                }
            });




        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```